# Push a new Object to an object nested Array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

Am trying to add a new object into my Redux initial States that was dispatched and I cant seem to make it works because am new to it. this is my initial State value

```
const initialState = {
  invoices: data,
  filterInvoice: data,
  toggleId: "",
  singleInvoice: [],
};
```

the data in front of the invoices is a local Json data am using to populate the states. The Data is an Array of objects. see the data value below

```
[
  {
    "id": "RT3080",
    "createdAt": "2021-08-18",
    "paymentDue": "2021-08-19",
    "description": "Re-branding",
    "paymentTerms": 1,
    "clientName": "Jensen Huang",
    "clientEmail": "jensenh@mail.com",
    "status": "paid",
    "senderAddress": {
      "street": "19 Union Terrace",
      "city": "London",
      "postCode": "E1 3EZ",
      "country": "United Kingdom"
    },
    "clientAddress": {
      "street": "106 Kendell Street",
      "city": "Sharrington",
      "postCode": "NR24 5WQ",
      "country": "United Kingdom"
    },
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "Brand Guidelines",
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 1800.9,
        "total": 1800.9
      }
    ],
    "total": 1800.9
  },
  {
    "id": "XM9141",
    "createdAt": "2021-08-21",
    "paymentDue": "2021-09-20",
    "description": "Graphic Design",
    "paymentTerms": 30,
    "clientName": "Alex Grim",
    "clientEmail": "alexgrim@mail.com",
    "status": "pending",
    "senderAddress": {
      "street": "19 Union Terrace",
      "city": "London",
      "postCode": "E1 3EZ",
      "country": "United Kingdom"
    },
    "clientAddress": {
      "street": "84 Church Way",
      "city": "Bradford",
      "postCode": "BD1 9PB",
      "country": "United Kingdom"
    },
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "Banner Design",
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 156.0,
        "total": 156.0
      },
      {
        "name": "Email Design",
        "quantity": 2,
        "price": 200.0,
        "total": 400.0
      }
    ],
    "total": 556.0
  },
]
```

going on, an object of the same data format would be dispatched into my reducer. so my problem is I dont get how I will add the object to the invoices initialState. My reducer

```
if (action.type === ActionTypes.DynamicInput) {
    let tempInvoice;

    //calculate totalValues
    const totalAmount = action.payload.items.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const { itemTotal } = curr;
      acc += parseFloat(itemTotal);
      return acc;
    }, 0);

    if (action.payload.createdAt) {
      const newDate = new Date(action.payload.createdAt).toLocaleDateString();
      const paymentDue = addDays(
        newDate,
        action.payload.paymentTerms
      ).toLocaleDateString();

      if (action.isDraft === true) {
        tempInvoice = {
          ...action.payload,
          createdAt: newDate,
          paymentDue: paymentDue,
          status: "draft",
          total: totalAmount,
        };
      } else {
        tempInvoice = {
          ...action.payload,
          createdAt: newDate,
          paymentDue: paymentDue,
          status: "pending",
          total: totalAmount,
        };
      }
    }

    // then initalizie the currentStates to add new action.payload objects coming from new invoice
    return {
      ...state,
      invoices: { ...state.invoices, tempInvoice },
    };
  }
```

I tried using the spread operator to get existing values and assign but it din work

```
  return {
      ...state,
      invoices: [ ...state.invoices, tempInvoice ],
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after so much debugging and why invoice array is changing, I noticed that TempInvoice is returning empty Objects. I.e It not been populated, Its null. so I refactored my code to look like this

```
if (action.payload.createdAt) {
      const newDate = new Date(action.payload.createdAt).toLocaleDateString();
      const paymentDue = addDays(
        newDate,
        action.payload.paymentTerms
      ).toLocaleDateString();

      if (action.isDraft === false) {
        tempInvoice = {
          ...action.payload,
          createdAt: newDate,
          paymentDue: paymentDue,
          id: getRandomAlphabet(),
          status: "draft",
          total: totalAmount,
        };
      } else {
        tempInvoice = {
          ...action.payload,
          createdAt: newDate,
          paymentDue: paymentDue,
          id: getRandomAlphabet(),
          status: "pending",
          total: totalAmount,
        };
      }
    } else {
      if (action.isDraft === false) {
        tempInvoice = {
          ...action.payload,
          status: "draft",
          id: getRandomAlphabet(),
          total: totalAmount,
        };
      } else {
        tempInvoice = {
          ...action.payload,
          status: "pending",
          id: getRandomAlphabet(),
          total: totalAmount,
        };
      }
    }
 return {
      ...state,
      invoices: [...state.invoices, tempInvoice],
     }
    };
```